# Cron job output files

Tags: php, cron

I have set up a cron job in my PHP project by using cpanel cronjob tool. But it is creating output files in root directory. I have find out a solution to block these output file creation, but my question is, if i will delete these already created files, will it cause any problem or will it affect cronjob program?

Answer (score 0):

It most likely wont(barring some sort of dependency of the cron job on the existence of a particular output file). You can block output file creation by adding 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null to the end of the cron command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

To block output file , iam using the following method, Is this correct?

Example: wget -q -O /dev/null http://mydomain.com/myfolder/myfile.php

Comment: If you are using wget, that is fine as well. it is easy to test out on the cli before adding it to the cron job.